# How to close jquery lighbox popup without clicking close option at top

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am using `jquery lightbox` plugin in my website.

The problem is whenever i have `lightbox` popup i need to click on `close button (X)` at the top.

Can anyone help so that when i click anywhere out of the popup box it should close.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159229/lightbox-click-outside-image-to-close

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $("#overlay").click(function(){$("#lightbox").hide(); });
```

Whenever we open a lightbox, in the background a div display having id "overlay". So if you want to close jquery lighbox popup without clicking close option, you can close it by clicking outside the lightbox. So outside the lightbox the div "overlay" exist and we can bind the click event with it to close the lightbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Here on StackOverflow we love it if you also include some explanation of why your suggested code solves the issue, not only a code snippet itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have different types of options to do that, if you want to close the popup with the close button using `fadeOut` or css inside `display:none`.

For example:

```
$("#close_button").click(function(){
               $(this).fadeOut(300);
```

or you can do this:

```
$(this).css({display:"none"});
```

This should work for you. Good luck.